# Android Sqlite query two tables into an arraylist

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have the following situation:

- Android sqlite database with two tables:

  table1 ——1:N —— table2

table1

```
- int id (PK)
- text field2
- text field3
- text field N…
```

table2

- int id (PK)
- int t1_id (FK)
- real field3
- real field N…

Next I have the following Android java structures:

```
Class Table1 {
int id;
String field2;
String field3;
String fieldN…;
ArrayList<Table2> atable2;
}

Class Table2 {
int id;
int t1_id;
double field3;
double fieldN…;
}

public ArrayList<Table1> atable1 = new ArrayList<Table1>();
```

So, I need to select data from database to the atable1 arraylist based on a condition like the following:

```
select * from table1 where table1.field2 = ‘Italy’;
```

The question is that the arraylist atable2 inside arraylist atable1 must be selected based on the field t1_id from table2 (table2.t1_id = table1.id).

So anyone can help me to build an efficient form of doing a query (for Android sqlite) to get these data, including the data from table2?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

PS

Comment: What query would you use? Why is that no efficient enough for you?

Comment: First, I got all zones:

openDatabase();

Cursor cur = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table1 " +
             "WHERE table1.field2 LIKE 'Italy'", null);

and copy all the records to the arraylist atable1

Next, I make a for cycle to get the atable2 arraylist inside atable1:

openDatabase()
for (int i=0; i < atable1.size(); i++) {

 Cursor cur = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table2 " +
             "WHERE table2.table1_id = '" + atable1.get(i).id + "'", null);

Next I copy all the records from cursor to atable1.get(i).atable2.

}

Comment: For the first query is normal a result with a 5000 until 15000 records. For the second query is normal a result with around 20 to 50 records for each atable1 entry.

With this approach, the second query is extremely slow (several minutes).

Is there any possibility to I extract all the information with only one query to the database?

Thanks a lot!
PS

Answer (score 0):

There is no efficient form of loading 350000 records into memory on a mobile device.

But you don't need to, because you will not be able to show all of them on the screen at the same time.

Change your app to dynamically load only the data for the objects currently visible on the screen.